# Change Facebook profile image via API

Tags: php, api, facebook

Is it possible to change someone's profile picture via the Facebook API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API/PHP - Is it possible to change a user's profile image via FB Graph API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370669/facebook-api-php-is-it-possible-to-change-a-users-profile-image-via-fb-graph)

Answer (score 4):

The [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) discusses [POSTing a picture](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo) to an account but I see nothing related to the direct altering of a user account. I suspect they only recognize GET requests under their RESTful API (for the user area). Thus, a no.

That's just information gleaned from the [Facebook API docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/), however. I could be missing something though.

Comment: or is  possible to change  picture of profile  via something else?

Comment: @newprog, aside from the UI itself, I get the distinct impression that you can't. If you haven't asked over at the Facebook developer forums (http://forum.developers.facebook.com), you may want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

not possible: [Facebook API/PHP - Is it possible to change a user's profile image via FB Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370669/facebook-api-php-is-it-possible-to-change-a-users-profile-image-via-fb-graph-a), and also my own experience.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is **not possible**, period. Although you can upload an image to the Graph API and then redirect the user to the permalink of that post :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by adding **makeprofile=1** at the end of uploaded photo url. You can find example (PHP) and demo here: http://4rapiddev.com/facebook-graph-api/php-change-facebook-profile-picture-with-graph-api/

Comment: this parameter is ignored in mobile browser.