# changing user's profile pic on facebook after getting user's approvment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a facebook app and wanted to ask if it's possible and does not violate facebook  regulations if i ask the user if he agrees to change his profile pic to a pic i show him and i change if he approves.

thanks in advance.

Nadav

Comment: What command are you using to change the profile pic?  Are you sure it doesn't violate Facebook's policy to change the user's profile pic (maybe you should have your attorney look into that one).

Comment: I was talking about this code: http://4rapiddev.com/facebook-graph-api/php-change-facebook-profile-picture-with-graph-api/      i was trying it on the application that they've put on their facebook and it changed my pic automatically after i've agreed to change

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API/PHP - Is it possible to change a user's profile image via FB Graph API?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4370669/facebook-api-php-is-it-possible-to-change-a-users-profile-image-via-fb-graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this answers your question...
[Facebook API/PHP - Is it possible to change a user's profile image via FB Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370669/facebook-api-php-is-it-possible-to-change-a-users-profile-image-via-fb-graph)
Check out the accepted answer on this question which says that you cannot change a profile pic using the API.

Comment: I've seen this already, thanks, but this is was not what i meant. i meant if the user agrees, can i change the pic after approved. i found a code on this page http://4rapiddev.com/facebook-graph-api/php-change-facebook-profile-picture-with-graph-api/ and there is a sample on facebook of how it works, but i was wondering if its legal to do if i notify the user before changing, thanks

Comment: We're not attorney's here, so any advice you get is worth the price paid.  You really should consult with your corporate attorney before proceeding.