# Changing user's profile picture

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

There's one question -  can I change the user's profile image in Facebook using Facebook Graph Api? I need it for my IOS application.

Comment: No you cannot see the thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370669/facebook-api-php-is-it-possible-to-change-a-users-profile-image-via-fb-graph)