# How can a user change their graph requested profile image to an image in their album

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, swift2, xcode7-beta3

In this app it generates the users FB profile image, but I want them to be able to select another image if they choose. Parse is my backend. The app runs fine and it goes to the users album, but the picture is not updated in the app. [image: FB Graph Request Code]re

[image: UIImagePickerController code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update the profile picture with the API. See the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/#Creating

More information - and possible workarounds:

- [how to set a facebook profile picture using the graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306786/how-to-set-a-facebook-profile-picture-using-the-graph-api)
- [Can I set a users profile image using the Facebook API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648859/can-i-set-a-users-profile-image-using-the-facebook-api)
- [Facebook API/PHP - Is it possible to change a user's profile image via FB Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370669/facebook-api-php-is-it-possible-to-change-a-users-profile-image-via-fb-graph)

Comment: Thanks for the link, and answering my question

Comment: you are welcome, please don't forget to accept my answer ;)