# How to write Facebook App that continuously update profile picture

Tags: facebook, documentation, facebook-apps

I want to know if its possible to create Facebook app that continuously update users profile picture. I can't see anything in the docs. Do you know if this is possible and if so any docs on implementing it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible for the User Profile. There is no way to update the profile picture with the API directly.

There are many Stackoverflow threads about this already, this one is very old but the answer is still correct: [Facebook API/PHP - Is it possible to change a user's profile image via FB Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370669/facebook-api-php-is-it-possible-to-change-a-users-profile-image-via-fb-graph)

Comment: How these apps works then?
[Profile Picture Flag](http://www.profilepictureflag.com)

Comment: try them. they don´t directly change the profile picture, there is an additional/manual step included. trust me, it is not possible, and there are plenty of stackoverflow threads about this already.