# How to change Facebook profile picture by using Facebook API in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, api

Is it possible to change Facebook profile picture by using Facebook API in PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370669/facebook-api-php-is-it-possible-to-change-a-users-profile-image-via-fb-graph

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the profile picture of a user using the Graph API.

See:
[Facebook Graph API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/picture/#Creating)